# What are genderless alternatives for female/male connectors?

Tags: word-request

I read on https://www.acm.org/diversity-inclusion/words-matter:

> female/male connectors: terms used for describing physical connectors in hardware systems. The terms are sexist and normative, and good alternatives such as socket and plug exist and are already common.

What are other alternatives for female/male connectors?

Comment: "are sexist and normative" — what's wrong with [normative](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/normative)? Was it being added in a superfluous fashion to lend more weight for the assertion?

Comment: @Levente I think it refers to the binary gender norm.

Comment: Ah, reinforcing something not about connectors, but about people; got it. Never seen it used like that. Thanks.

Comment: Woke gone mad again. We went through a similar wave in the 80s, but I'm going to stick with calling a spade a spade & not a manual earth moving implement, thank you ;) The basic principle that one has a sticky-out bit & the other has in innie-bit is always going to make teenagers giggle, no matter what you call them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> socket and plug

Those are the only ones I've found, though "receptacle" can be used in place of "socket."

Answer (score 2):

[Konstantinos Konstantinides](https://www.quora.com/profile/Konstantinos-Konstantinides) [pointed me](https://www.quora.com/What-are-genderless-alternatives-for-female-male-connectors/answer/Konstantinos-Konstantinides?__filter__=all&__nsrc__=notif_page&__sncid__=35654828632&__snid3__=47856682805) to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_of_connectors_and_fasteners#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DThe%20terms%20plug%2C%20pin%2C%20and%2Cintended%20for%20the%20non-specialist.):

> The terms **plug**, **pin**, and **prong** are also often used for "male" connectors, and **receptacle**, **socket**, and **slot** are used for "female" connectors. In many cases these terms are more common than *male* and *female*, especially in documentation intended for the non-specialist. These nearly synonymous terms can cause a fair amount of confusion when the designations are shortened in labels.

Answer (score 2):

On a related note, I wonder how ACM sees talk of male and female connectors as sexist. My own understanding of the term *sexism* is as Merriam-Webster defines it—“prejudice or discrimination based on sex”—and I don’t see who or what is being prejudged or discriminated against. Likewise, I wonder how they see the usage as normative, if by that they mean representing things as they **ought** to be. To me, the usage is simply a metaphor, and no metaphor is either perfect or universal.

I am certainly not decreeing how others ought to experience discourse, but merely describing how I experience it so that others may understand what it is I’m asking.